# Balancing (creating same number of rows for each individual) data

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2

Given a data.table as follows, `id1` is a subject-level ID, `id2` is a within-subject repeated-measure ID, `X` are data variables of which there are many. I want to balance the data such that every individual has the same number of rows (repeated measures), which is the `max(DT[,.N,by=id1][,N])`, but where `id1` and `id2` are adjusted as necessary, and `X` data values are replaced with `NA` for these new rows.

The following:

```
DT = data.table(
id1 = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
id2 = c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
X1 = letters[1:9],
X2 = LETTERS[1:9]
)
setkey(DT,id1)
```

Should look like:

```
DT = data.table(
id1 = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
id2 = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
X1 = c(letters[1:2],NA,NA,letters[3:5],NA,letters[6:9]),
X2 = c(LETTERS[1:2],NA,NA,LETTERS[3:5],NA,LETTERS[6:9])
)
```

How do you go about doing this using `data.table`? For-looping to be avoided as this data-set is huge. Is this a job for `reshape2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try:

```
 DT2 <- CJ(id1=1:3, id2=1:4)
 merge(DT,DT2, by=c('id1', 'id2'), all=TRUE)
```

Comment: @FBC No problem.  I am still searching whether there is a data.table unique method to solve this.

Comment: Solving this by merging the original data with another data.table, at least for me, is a sufficiently data.table-unique method so I'll accept this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slight variation on akrun's answer that's normally used for the problem at hand:

```
setkey(DT, id1, id2)
DT[CJ(unique(id1), unique(id2))]
```