# left_join(x,y) and NA

Tags: r, dplyr

After seeing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812747/balancing-creating-same-number-of-rows-for-each-individual-data) with a nice answer by @akrun, I wanted to play with `dplyr`. Here are the sample data from the post and akrun.

```
df = data.frame(
      id1 = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
      id2 = c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
      X1 = letters[1:9],
      X2 = LETTERS[1:9],
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
     )
df2 <- data.frame(
      id1 = rep(c(1:3), each = 4),
      id2 = rep(c(1:4), times = 3),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
     )
```

If I replicate akrun's answer, `merge()` perfectly works here.

```
df %>%
    do(merge(., df2, by = c("id1","id2"), all = TRUE))

   id1 id2   X1   X2
 1    1   1    a    A
 2    1   2    b    B
 3    1   3 <NA> <NA>
 4    1   4 <NA> <NA>
 5    2   1    c    C
 6    2   2    d    D
 7    2   3    e    E
 8    2   4 <NA> <NA>
 9    3   1    f    F
 10   3   2    g    G
 11   3   3    h    H
 12   3   4    i    I
```

Then, I thought `left_join(x,y)` would do. `left_join(x,y)` includes all of `x`, and matching rows of `y`. From the examples in the `dplyr` tutorial pdf from UseR!2014, I expected an identical result. But, that was not the case.

```
> df %>%
+     left_join(df2, .)
Joining by: c("id1", "id2")
   id1 id2   X1   X2
1    1   1    a    A
2    1   2    b    B
3    1   3 <NA> <NA>
4    1   4 <NA> <NA>
5    2   1 <NA> <NA>
6    2   2 <NA> <NA>
7    2   3 <NA> <NA>
8    2   4 <NA> <NA>
9    3   1 <NA> <NA>
10   3   2 <NA> <NA>
11   3   3 <NA> <NA>
12   3   4 <NA> <NA>
```

The first three rows indicate that `dplyr` was doing the right job. But, once it encountered `NA`, it generated `NA`s till the end. Is this a bug or did I do something wrong? Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: Another comparison: `plyr::join` behaves correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently a few bugs with `dplyr` and the `_join` functions:

- https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/542
- https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/455
- https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/450

I looks like they are being fixed. In the mean time, if you make sure the group-by variables are the same type (they aren't in your example - you can tell by using `str()`), then it should work:

```
df = data.frame(
  id1 = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
  id2 = c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
  X1 = letters[1:9],
  X2 = LETTERS[1:9],
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  id1 = as.numeric(rep(c(1:3), each = 4)),
  id2 = as.numeric(rep(c(1:4), times = 3)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

left_join(df2, df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. I tested your idea, and that solved the issue. It would be great if `_join()` can take integer and number as `merge()` can.

Comment: Hadley and team are working on it. I expect these issues to be resolved when version 0.3 is released.