# dplyr group by: add null groups

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I'm currently trying to get counts of observations that meet multiple criteria using dplyr, and group by city. For example:

```
datacount.by.city <- data %>% 
group_by(city) %>% 
filter(cond1 == TRUE | cond2 == TRUE) %>% 
tally()
```

I'm appending this condition to existing dataframe with a greater number of cities than is contained in these data. Is there a way to group_by(city) in this code while adding NA values for cities that are in my main dataframe but not in the data that I'm working on, so I can easily cbind to it and have the right number of columns in the right place?

Comment: Please make this more reproducible by including example input data and the expected output.

Comment: dplyr's bind_rows() and bind_cols() don't need your data to be ordered

Comment: City          Cond1  Cond2
City1 TRUE FALSE
City2 TRUE FALSE
City2 FALSE TRUE
 City1 FALSE TRUE

Turns to 

City  count
City1 2
City2 2
City3 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [left\_join(x,y) and NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813784/left-joinx-y-and-na)

Comment: Please have a thorough look at `left_join`. I  personally really like the https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If your full dataset were df for instance:

```
data <- df %>%
    subset(city=="A")

datacount.by.city <- data %>% 
   ddply(.(city),summarize,count=sum(cond1 == TRUE | cond2 == TRUE)) %>%
   right_join(df,by="city")
```

gives:

```
     city count cond1 cond2
1    A     1  TRUE  TRUE
2    B    NA  TRUE  TRUE
3    C    NA  TRUE  TRUE
```