# R: Insert missing dates in longitudinal data without losing information

Tags: r, date, time-series, data.table, panel-data

I have a longitudinal dataset in a data table, similar to the simplified example below:

```
> head(data)
   Country     ID        Date         Value
1:   AT        AT6306    2012-11-01   16.2
2:   AT        AT6306    2012-11-02   12.2
3:   AT        AT6306    2012-11-03   11.3
4:   AT        AT6306    2012-11-04   14.2
5:   AT        AT6306    2012-11-05   17.3
6:   AT        AT6306    2012-11-06   12.5

> tail(data)
   Country     ID        Date         Value
1:   SE        SE0935    2014-06-25   16.2
2:   SE        SE0935    2014-06-26   12.2
3:   SE        SE0935    2014-06-27   11.3
4:   SE        SE0935    2014-06-28   14.2
5:   SE        SE0935    2014-06-29   17.3
6:   SE        SE0935    2014-06-30   12.5
```

`ID` is the panel variable, it is entirely unique without overlaps between countries. The date range, looking only at unique values, ranges from `2012-10-23` to `2014-09-30`. Clearly, the ranges of `Date` are not identical for each `ID`. Moreover, there may be missing values. In order to have a balanced panel, I want to fill in the gaps of my dataset.

Adapting the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812747/balancing-creating-same-number-of-rows-for-each-individual-data/25858226#25858226), as suggsted by @akron, I do the following:

```
data2 <- data[, CJ(ID=unique(ID), Date=unique(Date))]
setkey(data2, ID, Date)

data.new <- merge(data, data2, by=c("ID", "Date"), all.y = TRUE)
setkey(data.new, ID, Date)
```

Using the option `all.y = TRUE`, R thus adds rows for every missing date in `data`. However, now all fields other than `ID` and `Date` are blank, if the row did not exist before in `data`. That is, my data looks something like this

```
> head(data.new)
   Country     ID        Date         Value
1:   NA        AT6306    2012-10-23   NA
2:   NA        AT6306    2012-10-24   NA
3:   NA        AT6306    2012-10-25   NA
4:   NA        AT6306    2012-10-26   NA
5:   NA        AT6306    2012-10-27   NA
6:   NA        AT6306    2012-10-28   NA
```

I do want the `Value` to be NA, since it is missing. However, since the `Country` does not change for a given `ID`, I would like the field to be filled.

Comment: Do these countries have the same range of dates?

Comment: Yes, the range is 2011-11-01 to 2014-06-30. I'll update the question to incorporate that fact

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25858226/559784) from eddi.

Comment: So, the first command creates a new data table with using a sequence to create a date range without gaps, the second assigns keys (whereby it also sorts the data table) and the third should map the Values on the newly created frame, correct? I got everything working up to the last command, where I get the error: `Error in bmerge(i <- shallow(i), x, leftcols, rightcols, io <- haskey(i),  : typeof x.Date (double) != typeof i.ID (integer)`

Comment: I should have noted that the ID is actually a factor that can contain letters and numbers.

Comment: @akrun, I don't see how you came up with your answer from the link I provided. It uses `CJ()` in `i` in a straightforward manner, after setting keys on `DT`. Why use it in `j`...?!?

Comment: @altabq, this Q very much feels like a duplicate of the one I linked. Read up on `?CJ`, and look at the usage on that post. It's a direct join. Set keys on `data` to `Country, ID, Date`. And use `DT[CJ(...)]` - that'll fill all missing values with NA by default.

Comment: @altabq, please provide reproducible data (code that we can copy/paste). Akron, what's the code you tried that gave you the wrong result? From what I can see, your and is a roundabout way of accomplishing `DT[CJ(...)]`.

Comment: @akrun You are right, the answer is almost exactly the same. I managed to create a new table using merge. I am having one slight problem though. I have a couple more fields that give attributes to the entities. So for each ID, there is the name of the entity and some other things. Is there a way to add that to DT2 using CJ?

Comment: @altabq It would be better if you provide `dput` output. ie. `dput(head(data,20))` . In the example I created, `Country` is character class.

Comment: @akrun, I would really like to do that but the data is proprietary. I thus cannot share a specific example. Basically, for each ID, I have a number of factor class columns, each row is unique to the ID. In the context `Country`, which for me is factor class: I use `data.new <- merge(data2, data, by=c("ID", "Date"), all.x = TRUE)` to match the two datasets. However, then Country will be `NA` for dates that did not previously exist in dData`. Is it possible to add the `Country` field already to the `data2` data table? `data2 <- data[, CJ(ID=unique(ID), Date=unique(Date)]`

Comment: @akrun, yes please. Basically, my problem is that by merging with the option `all.x = TRUE`, new rows are added for values that exist in `data2` (the gapless data table) but not in `data` (the original data table, which may contain gaps). Since `data2` is defined via `data2 <- data[, CJ(ID=unique(ID), Date=unique(Date)]`, it has no values for the other attributes of each entity (e.g. `Country`). Hence, the field contains. I think you should be able to reproduce this by leaving one country blank in the `data` data table.

Comment: @altabq If you check the output I posted, the Country field is there.

Comment: @altabq I updated the post. Please check if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dat)
setkey(DT, Date, Country, ID)
res <- DT[CJ(seq(min(Date), max(Date), by='1 day'), 
                        unique(Country), unique(ID))]

 head(res)
#    Country   ID       Date Value
#1:      AT  935 2012-11-01    NA
#2:      AT 6306 2012-11-01  16.2
#3:      SE  935 2012-11-01    NA
#4:      SE 6306 2012-11-01    NA
#5:      AT  935 2012-11-02    NA
#6:      AT 6306 2012-11-02  12.2
```

#### Update

One option you could do is

```
DT <- data.table(dat)
DT[,CountryID:= paste(Country,ID)]
setkey(DT, Date, CountryID)
DT1 <- DT[CJ(unique(Date), unique(CountryID))][,
      c('Country', 'ID'):=  list(gsub("[ 0-9]", "", CountryID),
               gsub("[^ 0-9]", "", CountryID)),][,-5L]


head(DT1,3)
#     Country    ID       Date Value
#1:      AT  6306 2012-11-01  16.2
#2:      SE   935 2012-11-01    NA
#3:      AT  6306 2012-11-02  12.2

nrow(DT1)
#[1] 24
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(Country = c("AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", 
"SE", "SE", "SE", "SE", "SE", "SE"), ID = c(6306L, 6306L, 6306L, 
6306L, 6306L, 6306L, 935L, 935L, 935L, 935L, 935L, 935L), Date = structure(c(15645, 
15646, 15647, 15648, 15649, 15650, 15669, 15670, 15671, 15672, 
15673, 15674), class = "Date"), Value = c(16.2, 12.2, 11.3, 14.2, 
17.3, 12.5, 16.2, 12.2, 11.3, 14.2, 17.3, 12.5)), .Names = c("Country", 
"ID", "Date", "Value"), row.names = c("1:", "2:", "3:", "4:", 
"5:", "6:", "1:1", "2:1", "3:1", "4:1", "5:1", "6:1"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem that I have with e.g. country is that I do not add it into DT as `unique`, since the `ID` is already unique across countries. So, I only use `data2 <- data[, CJ(ID=unique(ID), Date=unique(Date)]`. But then I get NAs for the countries. If I do add `Country=unique(Country)`, the matrix gets much larger than necessary, since the length will then be `unique(Date)*unique(ID)*unique(Country)` instead of `unique(Date)*unique(ID)`, which is the intended size.

Comment: @altabq Based on your code, I get 24 rows and with `NAs` on Country.  So, you want to change the NAs or remove the rows from code to get 24 rows?

Comment: I would like to change the `NAs` to have the matching `Country` in there. Would it be possible to add e.g. non-unique fields already to the `CJ` table?

Comment: @altabq Are these `IDs` unique for each `Country` or is there overlaps?

Comment: the `IDs` are all unique. I should have chosen a better example than in my question, since they look more like `AT6306` and `SE0935`. So, `Country` is not needed for merging, but the information should be retained.

Comment: I will rewrite my question to the one it basically boils down to now.